# How to show video or image using url in html?

Tags: php, html, image, url, iframe

I want to show the urls, urls can be of video or image, I want to show the video or image using the url.

Urls could be anything, Facebook videos, Instagram videos, Facebook images, Instagram images etc.

I want to load these and show. I tried to use iFrame and video to show videos but its not working. And for image I tried to show in image tag but did not work.

urls can b like

https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10154659446236729/

this for video

https://www.instagram.com/p/BSS3dVZlgXw/

This can be for image.

How can I show this image or preview of a image and onClick of that can open it in new browser? Also for video can we do this way?

Here is getPosts.php for now I am showing this in a table.

```
     <?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

include 'Database.php';

$database = new Database(Constants::DBHOST,Constants::DBUSER,Constants::DBPASS,Constants::DBNAME);

$dbConnection = $database->getDB();

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$posts='';

if (count($results > 0)) {

    $posts.='<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Url</th></tr>';

    foreach($results as $row) {

        $posts.='<tr><td>'.$row['title'].'</td> <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
        if (strcmp($row['url_type'],"2") || strcmp($row['url_type'],"") || strcmp($row['url_type'],"5")|| strcmp($row['url_type'],"7"))
            {
                '<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="'.$row['url'].'" type="video/mp4">
</video>';
            }

    }

} else {

    $posts.='<tr><td>No data found</td></tr>';

}

$posts.='</table>';

echo $posts;

?>
```

Test was like this for IFrame and video tag but Iframe worked for one url and not for other and video tag dosent work.:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="https://youtu.be/GHWHrgDqTyY" type="video/youtube">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10154651089866729/">
</iframe>

<img src="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/photos/a.376995711728.190761.20531316728/10155085288566729/?type=3&theater" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">


</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a facebook video, the code should be like this :

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10154651089866729%2F&show_text=0&width=400" width="420" height="345" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Same for an image. If you want to display your image, just right something like this :

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fposts%2F10155085288566729%3A0&width=500" width="500" height="665" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: can I show video using video tag? so that I can view full screen video if I want? With I frame its working but what if I want to see this in a full screen or new tab on click on it?

Comment: did you change the link? I can't see the video with the url which I specified.

Comment: I did not change anything. I will read documentation on how to have full screen option + new tab.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10154651089866729/  this is not the link You have given in your answer